# Formal Proof of WFF using Rules of Inference

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs, hilbert-calculus

I am currently hung up on a practice problem that requires a formal proof of a WFF using ONLY rules of inference. I've been attempting this for hours, but it seems like there is something i'm missing. In this case, I know I need to get a C or ¬C to use Modus Ponens then Addition, but its not working for me.

WFF: (C→A) ∧ (¬C→B) → A∨B

[EDIT] Latest attempt:

1. (C→A) | Premise for Conditional Proof
2. (¬C→B) | Premise for Conditional Proof
3. ¬C | Premise for Indirect Proof
4. B | 2, 3 Modus Ponens
5. A∨B | 4, Addition
6. ¬C∧B | 3, 4 Conjunction

Comment: There are many different deductive systems, so it's best to outline the system you're using or given a reference. I've done a good bit of logic and I'm not sure what "P for IP" means. (But for what it's worth, $C\lor \lnot C$ is a tautology, so you can certainly prove it. And the prove won't involve any $A$'s or $B$'s or nothing.)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right trail. You may either:

**(1) Accept the Law of Excluded Middle** as an axiom, and eliminate that disjunction.

- $(C\to A)~\land ~(\neg C\to B)$ by premise.
- $C\vee\neg C$ by LEM

  - $C$ by assumption
  - *yadayadayadah.*
  - $A\vee B$ by *reasons*
- $C\to(A\vee B)$ by conditional introduction

  - $\neg C$ by assumption
  - $\neg C\to B$ by conjunction elimination (simplification)
  - $B$ by conditional elimination (modus ponens)
  - $A\vee B$ by disjunction introduction
- $\neg C\to(A\vee B)$ by conditional introduction (deduction)
- $A\vee B$ by disjunction introduction

---

**(2) Accept Double Negation Elimination** as a rule of inference and Reduce to Absurdity.

- $(C\to A)~\land ~(\neg C\to B)$ by premise.

  - $\neg(A\vee B)$ by assumption

    - $C$ by assumption
    - *yadayadayadah.*
    - $\bot$ by *reasons*
  - $\neg C$ by negation introduction
  - $\neg C\to B$ by conjunction elimination (simplification)
  - $B$ by conditional elimination (modus ponens)
  - $A\vee B$ by disjunction introduction
  - $\bot$ by negation elimination (sometimes called "contradiction introduction")
- $\neg\neg (A\vee B)$ by negation introduction
- $A\vee B$ by double negation elimination